# Как получить mac адреса роутеров? c#

Tags: c#

[На codeplex](http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/41381#213980) есть что-то похожее, но там нету получения mac адреса устройства. Как можно получить весь список имен и мак адресов роутеров (wifi точек)?

Comment: Посмотрите тут [Retrieve list of IP and MAC addresses of computers in a Local Network](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aab46f77-3fde-4f49-945a-61d1a62c9548/retrieve-list-of-ip-and-mac-addresses-of-computers-in-a-local-network?forum=netfxnetcom)

Comment: Есть такой протокол ARP, И он хранит в системе таблицы соответствий ip и mac адресов. Есть команда arp для манипуляций с этой информацией. Значит должны быть какие-то функции API

Comment: Там он показывает все IP'шники и мак адреса, подключенные к wifi точке (те сколько людей сидит на моем wifi'e). А мне нужно список wifi точек около меня, с мак адресом (bssid). (на codeplex есть имя, сигнал, алгоритм шифрования точки, но мак так и не нашел там)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BSSID (а также уровень сигнала в дБм) можно получить, вызвав метод `GetNetworkBssList`:

```
// вывод MAC в виде ХХ:ХХ:ХХ:ХХ:ХХ:ХХ
static string GetStringForBSSID(byte[] bssid)
{
    var result = new StringBuilder();

    result.Append(bssid[0].ToString("X2"));
    for (int i = 1; i < bssid.Length; ++i) {
        result.Append(":").Append(bssid[i].ToString("X2"));
    }

    return result.ToString();
}

static string GetStringForSSID(Wlan.Dot11Ssid ssid)
{
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ssid.SSID, 0, (int)ssid.SSIDLength);
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var client = new WlanClient();

    if (client.Interfaces.Length < 1)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Wireless adapter not found.");

    Console.WriteLine("SSID\t\t\tBSSID\t\t\tRSSI");
    Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------");

    WlanClient.WlanInterface nic = client.Interfaces[0];
    foreach (Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork network in nic.GetAvailableNetworkList(0)) {
        string ssid = GetStringForSSID(network.dot11Ssid);

        Wlan.WlanBssEntry[] bssList =
            nic.GetNetworkBssList(
                network.dot11Ssid,
                network.dot11BssType,
                network.securityEnabled);

        int rssi = 0;
        string bssid = "";
        if (bssList.Length > 0) {
            rssi = bssList[0].rssi;
            bssid = GetStringForBSSID(bssList[0].dot11Bssid);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("{0,-16}\t{1,-8}\t{2} dBm", ssid, bssid, rssi);
    }
}
```